# .sqlite files being ignored although not in the ignore list

Tags: git, sqlite, gitignore

I have checked the global ignore rules in `.gitignore_global`, then I checked the global rules in `.gitconfig`, but I could not find such file in my system (Ubuntu Linux, nothing in `~/`). Then I also checked the project's `./git` directory but it does not have any `.gitignore` file as well.

In spite of all this, when I try `git add .`, git warns me that it will ignore `.sqlite` files per my git ignore pattern.

I have never set such patter so it's got to be some default behaviour.

Where can I find `gitignore` while which is preventing adding of SQLite files to the repository?

I am still pretty new to Git.

Comment: Any `.gitignore` file in the file's directory or one of its parents?

Comment: `.gitignore` in repo tree and `.git/info/exclude`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a recent enough git version (you must have git 1.8.3.3+), you can use [`git check-ignore`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-check-ignore):

```
git check-ignore -v .sqlite
```

That will give you the file and line of the .gitignore responsible for your add not succeeding.